# How to remove box shadow from Image?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a loading Image (while page loading) which was surrounded by box like shadow as like this:

I want this Image to show as like this:

This is the code I tried to fix

```
.modal-dialog {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Can some one help to fix this?

Comment: Why not edit the loading image? Or remove the shadow in the CSS?

Comment: @VDWWD -how to edit this in CSS? any sample code?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't provided any code....

Comment: Hi @Jaggi welcome to SO! As the others have said, we'll need more information before we can know what the problem is. Please start by reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then include code following the recommendations at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have .selector and .selector.noshadow class

```
.selector {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #333;
}

.selector.noshadow {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```